# linear or polynomial regression?

Tags: lme4-nlme, linear

I am observing measurements of eyes.

I have patients who visit repeatedly; I measure the RNFL (retinal nerve fiber layer) in both eyes each time. The primary predictor for RNFL measurements is `Status` i.e. glaucoma (or not).

I have 3x such sets of such observations.

I need to account for:

- the timing of the measurement
  (i.e. months since disease onset,`m_since_ON`)
- the age of the patient

And to control for

- the correlation between the eyes (in the same patient)
- repeated measures in the same eye/ patient

Using `R`, I've chosen a linear model with mixed/random effects, using `lmer` as follows:

```
lmer1 <-lmer (pRNFL ~ Status + m_since_ON  + 
              Status:m_since_ON + 
              (1 + m_since_ON | Eye/ID) + 
              (1 + m_since_ON | age), 
             data=data_head)
```

Then:

```
lsmeans(lmer1, pairwise ~ Status)
data_head$fit <- predict(lmer1, re.form=NA)
lsmeans(lmer1, pairwise ~ Status | m_since_ON, 
        at=list(m_since_ON=
                c(3,12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120,132,144,156)))
data_head$fit <- predict(lmer1, re.form=NA)
```

And to plot:

```
ggplot(data=data_head, 
       aes(m_since_ON, pRNFL, group=Status, col=Status)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit, lty=Status), size=0.8) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.3) + 
  theme_bw()
```

or:

```
ggplot(data=data_head, 
       aes(x=m_since_ON, y=pRNFL)) +
  geom_point(alpha=1, size=2) +
  aes(colour=Status) +
  geom_path(aes(group='ID'))
```

However, when I change the `ggplot` to a *polynomial* curve, as below

```
ggplot(data=data_head, 
       aes(x=m_since_ON, y=pRNFL)) + 
  geom_point(size=2, alpha=1,  
             aes(color=Status)) + # colour points by group
  stat_smooth(method="lm", 
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), 
              aes(color= Status)) + 
  ylab("pRNFL (volume)") + 
  xlab("m_since_ON (months)") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

I get different *p* values to the linear model with mixed effects.

Is that because the polynomial curve affects model fitting with `lmer`?

THis is a subset:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? As a new user, you won't be able to post images with your question, but a small dataset with the relevant variables would go a long way here...

Comment: I've edited the post with a picture if that's alright. Thanks! Lili

Comment: Not sure where you’re getting different p values. You only show one model, and those plots don’t generate p values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rvl.  If you see in the second plot, there is a polynomial "lm", could that explain the difference? 
Also Is it possible to get that different p values when you use polynomial rather than linear? (sorry this might be a stupid question...

Comment: Well, `lm` and `lmer` fit different models based on different assumptions, so it'd be a surprise if P values matched. Moreover, if you were to include polynomial effects for `m_since_ON` in your `lmer` model, that'd be a different model, again with different P values. So yes, if I interpret your question literally, including a polynomial trend would change your P values. But somehow I don't think that's what you're actually asking about.

Comment: It also seems like `age` should be a predictor in the fixed-effects part of the model rather than a grouping factor. It would be worthwhile to have a face-to-face consultation with someone in a statistics group near you, for help in making meaningful modeling choices.

Comment: Many thanks, @rvl, very well spotted the 'age' mistake. And yes, maybe I don't fully understand how to fix the model... I will have a face to face meeting soon

Comment: would though be possible to use lmer and polynomial trend on the same model or that is incompatible?